# I’m not following Newton’s derivation of $\frac{d}{dx}(\arcsin x)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, derivatives, binomial-theorem

[This answer](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/3175) summarizes how Newton determined the derivative of the arcsine function. However, I am having trouble following it to completion. Here is how I understand it thus far (with a bit of narrative in my own words):

---

Isaac Newton had already extended the binomial theorem to exponents other than nonnegative integers. He took the binomial coefficient to be

$$\binom{n}{r}=\frac{1}{r!} \prod_{i=0}^{r-1}(n-i) = \frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-r+1)}{r!}$$

and thusly, the generalized binomial theorem

$$(x+y)^n = \sum_{r=0}^\infty \binom{n}{r}x^{n-r}y^r$$

could be applied to expressions such as $\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

This is convenient, because the unit circle in the first and second quadrants is modeled by

$$\begin{align}y=\sin\theta
&= \sqrt{1-x^2} \\
&= \left(1-x^2\right)^{1/2} \\
&= \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/2}{r}(1)^{1/2-r}\left(-x^2\right)^r \\
\end{align}$$

Computing the initial terms gives

$$\sin\theta = \frac{\left(-x^2\right)^0}{2^0} + \frac{\left(-x^2\right)^1}{2^1} + \frac{\left(-x^2\right)^2}{-2^3} + \frac{\left(-x^2\right)^3}{2^4}+\frac{5\left(-x^2\right)^4}{2^7} + \cdots$$

---

This is where I get lost. I don’t want to waste time on this method if I’m headed down the wrong path.

Could someone share how it’s done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's too long to put in as a comment, so I'll post here instead.

Based on the answer in the link, Newton did not use the method to find the derivative of $\arcsin⁡ x$. He uses the power series of $\arcsin⁡ x$ itself to find the power of series of $\sin⁡ x$ hence $\frac{d}{dx}\sin⁡ x$.

So picking from where you left of,
Newton has found that
$$\sin x=\sum_{i=0}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}}$$

After some manipulation, Newton has established that:
$$\cos x = \sqrt{1-\sin^2x}\tag{1}$$
and
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sin⁡ x=\cos x\tag{2}$$

Now, the usual:

Letting $u=\arcsin x$, we have
$$\sin u =x$$
Hence,
\begin{align}
\frac{du}{dx}&=\frac{du}{d\sin u}\\
&=\left(\frac{d\sin u}{du}\right)^{-1}\\
&=\frac{1}{\cos u}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2u}}\\
\frac{d}{dx}\arcsin x&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Of course—the derivative of $\sin$ must be confirmed before one can determine the derivative of $\arcsin$! I feel very silly now

Comment: I feel like this appropriately answers this post.  I may end up posting an additional question that requests more detail, but that is no reason not to give you the green check.